# Android: Save date normally to sqlite but sort by date considering month and day

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have seen number of post about storing date.

I am still not getting the fine and exact approach about saving it to a sqlite database.

I am able to store it, but during sorting I need to consider only month and day just like birthday where years doesn't matter.

What will be the query if I want to get the row whose date is 2 or 3 days in advance, like 2nd march row if searched on 28 Feb?

Comment: How are you storing it? Unix epoch or some other wonky format?

Comment: I am storing it as Text,but how to sort it

Comment: Right. Text. What **format** are you using for your text then?

Comment: am not getting .I am using TEXT as  strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").here I am not using this time HH:MM......Am i right or should i seek a better way.......Actually I am trapped how to proceed.

Comment: Any way to save it normally and sort accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by checking out the SQLite documentation of [date & time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

For instance, to solve your problem "*And what will be the query if i want to get the row whose date is 2 or 3 days in advance*" you'd use julian day calculations, such as this example that you can execute directly in the `sqlite3` shell:

```
create TABLE example (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, date TEXT NOT NULL);
insert into example (date) values ('2011-01-02');
insert into example (date) values ('2011-04-02');
insert into example (date) values ('2012-02-26');
insert into example (date) values ('2012-02-27');
insert into example (date) values ('2012-02-28');
insert into example (date) values ('2012-02-29');
insert into example (date) values ('2012-03-01');
insert into example (date) values ('2012-03-02');
insert into example (date) values ('2012-03-03');
select date from example where julianday(date) - julianday('now') < 3 AND julianday(date) - julianday('now') > 0;
```

This would return (given that "today" is feb 28th) all the days that are one, two or three days in the future:

```
2012-02-29
2012-03-01
2012-03-02
```

**Edit:** To only return rows, regardless of year, you could do something like this - using a `VIEW` (again, exampl is directly in SQLite):

```
create view v_example as select _id, date,
    strftime("%Y", 'now')||'-'||strftime("%m-%d", date) as v_date from example;
```

This `VIEW` would return the date & times in your database "rebased" on the current year - which, of course could introduce all manner of wonky behavior with leap years.

You can select all the dates like this in that case:

```
select date from v_example where 
    julianday(v_date) - julianday('now') < 3 AND
    julianday(v_date) - julianday('now') > 0 ORDER BY v_date;
```

Which would return:

```
2012-02-29
2012-03-01
2001-03-01
2012-03-02
2010-03-02
```

Comment: It will also consider year while sorting.Actually I need to sort w/o year considerations

Comment: Yes, an event wouldn't be "two days ahead" if it's in another year. If you need to alter your stored date & time values you'd do that with the strfmttime function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by day and month consider storing the date as string in the format ddMMyyyy (you need two digits for day and month, otherwise the sorting will be flawed). Sorting by increasing values will give you dates sorted by day and month (and then year).

You can even do range query with string but you have to compute the query string.

Alternatively you may store the date as milliseconds in an additional column (this is the usual format for dates in the database) and do the range queries more easily with integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use strftime() in SQLite to strip of the year and then do a comparison.

```
select * from sometable where strftime('%m-%d', somecolumn) = '02-28'
```

This will do a query of all rows for February 28th. But performance might be hurt if you have a large table and need to do a string conversion of every row for comparison. Maybe store the day and month in two additional columns if this query is performed often?