# How to sort in database using Unix time stamp?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using an Database to store Dates and few values.I am  storing them using Unix time stamp and want to sort it out using months HOW CAN I DO IT ?

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

```
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(name VARCHAR,data VARCHAR,date VACHAR,epoch LONG(20));");

    }
```

The table gives an output :

name:ABC data:somedata date:06/12/2014 epoch:1407412931

How will i sort the table to find all the entries of an particular month ?
Please provide an detail explanation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976205/sqlite-order-by-month-number-in-a-yyyy-mm-dd-format / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480481/android-save-date-normally-to-sqlite-but-sort-by-date-considering-month-and-day and more online... try

Comment: I recommend to add new column in your database with month or every criteria you  use to sort registers. It's a common practise

Comment: Show some example rows and the desired output.

Comment: THANK YOU ALL @Xenione i used your method.